# REACT-EXPORT-EXCEL Value con Objeto Anidado

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Buenas noches comunidad , en esto momentos estoy utilizando la dependencia REACT-EXPORT-EXCEL que me genera un excel a partir de un array de objetos ,en mi caso uno de mis valores es un objeto anidado en una de las propiedades del objeto. En todos los ejemplos cuando se va a crear las columnas del archivo la sintaxys es la siguiente:

```
<ExcelColumn label="NombreDeLaColumna" value="NombreDeLaPropiedadEnMiObjeto">
```

No se como hacer para acceder a la propiedad que esta en mi objeto anidado y les coloco mi codigo a ver si me pueden ayudar por favor :

```
let driver =  [
{
  id: 0,
  rut: "24586934l",
  name: "John",
  phone: "936855642",
  active: true,
  transport_company:{
id:0,
name:"fastTrucks"
}}
]

 <ExcelFile element={<Button>Exportar</Button>} filename="DriverList">
          <ExcelSheet data={driver} name="Lista de Conductores">
            <ExcelColumn label="RUT" value="rut"/>
            <ExcelColumn label="Nombre" value="name"/>
            <ExcelColumn  label="Transportista" value={driver[0].transport_company.name}/>
            <ExcelColumn label="Teléfono" value="phone"/>
            <ExcelColumn label="Estado" value="active"/>
          </ExcelSheet>
        </ExcelFile>
```

Answer (score 0):

logre conseguir la solución y la dejaré por si alguien la necesita a futuro. Consiste en pasar entre llaves una funcion que hace el trabajo del metodo .map y te da acceso a los items del objeto anidado :

```
<ExcelFile element={<Button>Exportar</Button>} filename="DriverList">
      <ExcelSheet data={driver} name="Lista de Conductores">
        <ExcelColumn label="RUT" value="rut"/>
        <ExcelColumn label="Nombre" value="name"/>
        <ExcelColumn  label="Transportista" value={(col) => col.transport_company.name}/>
        <ExcelColumn label="Teléfono" value="phone"/>
        <ExcelColumn label="Estado" value="active"/>
      </ExcelSheet>
    </ExcelFile>
```